# How to delete object/row with jquery (post form)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a model posts where users can edit and delete their own posts. My index page is a table with a few columns for each post. One of them holds a form for the delete button. Is there any examples on how you jquery submit a post/delete form with rails? I need to pass the status back to the user. Eg. posts deleted, access denied etc and remove the row if successfull.

Best regards.
Asbjørn Morell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the action is successful the response will be a successful one (i.e. 200 OK). In your jQuery you can add an error function if the request encounters an error:

```
error: function() {
  // the item has not been deleted
  // and we encountered an error
}
```

Then in your Controller if you want to explicitly return your own error:

```
render :text => 'Could not compute!', :status => :unprocessable_entity
```

Or [any other error](http://www.codyfauser.com/2008/7/4/rails-http-status-code-to-symbol-mapping). Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello,

I ended up simple checking the flash[] variable.

Controller:
if @post.destroy
  flash[:note] = "Post was destroyed"
end

js.erb
<% if flash[:note] == "Post destroyed" %>
  Hide the row etc.
<% end %>
Display flash text

Answer (score -2):

You should look into the link_to_remote method; it uses AJAX -- I assume that what you mean by 'JQuery'.

I normally do something like:

```
<%= link_to_remote "Delete", :url => some_path(@object), :method => :delete %>
```

Answer (score -2):

link_to_remote. Will create inline Javascript that generates a post form. This will not work if Javascript is disabled.

I have created a standard html form, that works without Javascript, and would like to spice it up with jquery if Javascript is enabled.

```
<% form_for @post, :html => { :method => 'delete' } do |f| %>
    <%= submit_tag "Delete", :name => "delete" %>
<% end %>
```

[I found this blob last night](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/02/25/unobtrusive-destroy-links-in-rails-using-jquery), and it covers almost what I would like to do. The only thing I can't figure out, is how I return an error or success from the controller.